# Create dropdown element which opens and closes by button click

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I want a button that can open and close area which contains clickable controls. Currently I try to implement this with popup.
XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="PopupTrouble.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid Height="200" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Content="Open popup" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Popup x:Name="PopupInstance"
               AllowsTransparency="True"
               StaysOpen="False">
            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Some other clickable controls"/>
                    <RadioButton IsChecked="True" Content="Option one" GroupName="Group"></RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton IsChecked="False" Content="Option two" GroupName="Group"></RadioButton>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind file:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace PopupTrouble
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => PopupInstance.IsOpen = !PopupInstance.IsOpen;
    }
}
```

The problem is when popup is open button reopens it instead of closing it. If I'm right, this happens because popup is losing focus when I click button. I can't just set StaysOpen property to true because in that way popup will remain during mouse scroll or mouse click on other controls.
[Gif with current behavior (gifyu.com)](https://gifyu.com/image/SE3Sn)

Is there any way to change this behavior and  make WPF don't change focus when I click button?

I tried to implement this with FocusManager and check if new element which get focused is button, but get another problem - controls in popup don't work correctly.

Comment: Why do you want the popup to close "during mouse scroll or mouse click on other controls" if you have another button just to close it? When should the popup be closed exactly? Why do you need to close it in your button click event handler at all?

Comment: @mm8 I want to create a user control like timepicker or datepicker. It has text box and button which open popup with other controls like calendar. Popup should close when user click button and popup already was open, when user click other controls or scroll mouse. I use popup because this control could be presented on foreground regardless of ZIndex value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this solution will suit you without using Code Behind.

```xml
    <Grid Height="200" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton"
                          IsChecked="False">
                <ToggleButton.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="Open popup"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Content" Value="Close popup"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ToggleButton.Style>
            </ToggleButton>
        <Popup x:Name="PopupInstance"
                AllowsTransparency="True"
                IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=toggleButton, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Some other clickable controls"/>
                    <RadioButton IsChecked="True" Content="Option one" GroupName="Group"></RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton IsChecked="False" Content="Option two" GroupName="Group"></RadioButton>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
```

> popup doesn't close when I scroll mouse or click outside popup or button.

It is possible to make the Popup close when the button loses focus:

```xml
            <Popup x:Name="PopupInstance"
                   AllowsTransparency="True"
                   IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=toggleButton, Mode=TwoWay}"
                   StaysOpen="{Binding IsFocused, ElementName=toggleButton}">
```

Or yet this variant:

```xml
    <Popup x:Name="PopupInstance"
            AllowsTransparency="True"
            IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=toggleButton, Mode=TwoWay}"
            StaysOpen="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=toggleButton}">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's really great to implement this only with xaml. Unfortunately, popup doesn't close when I scroll mouse or click outside popup or button.

Comment: @GreezXII , Try the variant from the addition of my answer.

Comment: Thank you for addition. Still doesn't work. Button reopens popup if I click radio button. Also, popup doesn't close if I click outside popup or button. Here is a [GIF file](https://gifyu.com/image/SE373), I hope this would help to understand the issue.

Comment: @GreezXII , I added another implementation  variant to my answer.

Comment: The last variant works great except the toggle button still reopens if the popup was already opened. But from here I managed to solve this. I changed IsOpen binding mode to OneWay and added event handler to closed event of popup:
`if (toggleButton.IsMouseOver == false) toggleButton.IsChecked = false;`